How to add numeric and space and maxlength in input
if (model.value.length === 6 && !/^\d+$/.test(model.value)) {
  //Write something out
}
  

This works fine when when you write the number like "123456" but I want it to be ok to write it like this too "123 456", is that possible?

/^\d{6}$/.test(model.value.replaceAll(" ", "")

if (/^\s*(\d\s*){6}$/.test(model.value)) { ...

In the title there's "maxlength", but the code checks for exact length. Which one is needed? The purpose may also matter, like 004671 may be okay for a PIN-code or something similar, but it's not an actual 6-digit number.

Remove the spaces from model.value before checking the length and contents.
let val = model.value.replaceAll(" ", "");
if (val.length === 6 && !/^\d+$/.test(value)) {
  // do something
}

